# NITE Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ros, kinect, nite, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to install NITE on Ubuntu 10.04? In ROS the page seems to be empty. The only download that I could find was on <[openni.org](http://openni.org)>, and it was for Ubuntu 10.10.

Update: What commands do I use to run the NITE package? I want to use the "Prime Sense User Tracker Viewer" that it shows on the page.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10441/nite-ubuntu-10.04/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package is named nite-dev -> `sudo apt-get install nite-dev`

Its source is listed as a ROS source, so you will have to have [ubuntu setup for a package based installation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu#diamondback.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Configure_your_Ubuntu_repositories). (You don't need to install from packages though.)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-06-30**:
I was able to install the package, but how do I use it?